# I'm trying to upload photos to mongo db with node.js multer but I get error buffer not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb

#### dialog.component.html

```
   <input type="file" name="img" (change)="onImageSelected($event)" accept="image/*">
```

### dialog.component.ts

```
this.formValue = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      tags: ['', Validators.required],
      favorite: ['', Validators.required],
      cookTime: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/)]],
      origins: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      img: [''], // Yeni form alanı: imageUrl
    });
    //setting formvalues for updating action
    if (this.row) {
      this.actionButton = 'Update';
      this.formValue.controls['name'].setValue(this.row.name);
      this.formValue.controls['tags'].setValue(this.row.tags);
      this.formValue.controls['favorite'].setValue(this.row.favorite);
      this.formValue.controls['cookTime'].setValue(this.row.cookTime);
      this.formValue.controls['origins'].setValue(this.row.origins);
      this.formValue.controls['price'].setValue(this.row.price);
      this.formValue.controls['img'].setValue(this.row.img);
    }
  }
  onImageSelected(event: Event) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
      const file = input.files[0];
      this.formValue.patchValue({ img: file }); // Seçilen dosyayı form alanına ata
      console.log(this.formValue)
    }
  }



  postItem() {
    if (this.formValue.invalid) return;
    console.log(this.formValue)
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('img', this.formValue.value.img); // FormData'ya seçilen dosyayı ekleyin
  
    this.foodService.uploadImage(formData).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response)
        const fv = this.formValue.value;
        const food: Food = {
          name: fv.name,
          tags: fv.tags,
          favorite: fv.favorite,
          cookTime: fv.cookTime,
          origins: fv.origins,
          price: fv.price,
          img: {
            data: response.data,
            contentType: response.contentType
          },
          id: fv.name
        };
       
        this.foodService.postItemApi(food).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.formValue.reset();
          this.toastr.success('Product Added', 'Success');
        });
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error('Error while uploading image:', error);
        // Yükleme sırasında hata durumu
      }
    );
  }
```

### food.service.ts

```
 uploadImage(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    console.log(123)
    const endpoint = `http://localhost:5000/api/foods/dash`; // API'nin dosya yükleme endpoint'i
    return this.http.post(endpoint, formData);
  }
```

### food.model.ts

```
export interface Food{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    price:number;
    tags: string[];
    favorite:boolean;
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String,
      },
    origins: string[];
    cookTime:string;
    
}

export const FoodSchema = new Schema<Food>(
    {
        name: {type: String, required:true},
        price: {type: Number, required:true},
        tags: {type: [String]},
        favorite: {type: Boolean, default:false},
        img: {
            data: { type: Buffer, required: true },
            contentType: { type: String, required: true }
          },
        origins: {type: [String], required:true},
        cookTime: {type: String, required:true}
    },{
        toJSON:{
            virtuals: true
        },
        toObject:{
            virtuals: true
        },
        timestamps:true
    }
);
```

### food.router.ts

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   
    cb(null, '../uploads/'); // Dosyaların kaydedileceği klasörü belirtin
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // Dosya adını koruyun
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Dosya yükleme endpoint'i
router.post('/dash', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
 

  try {

  const file = req.file;

  if (!file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
  }

  // Dosyanın veri ve MIME türü bilgilerini döndürün
  const data = file.buffer;
  console.log(file)
  console.log(data)
  const contentType = file.filename;
  res.status(200).json({ data, contentType });
  
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error during file upload:', error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'File upload failed' });
}
});

router.post('/dash/products', async (req, res) => {
const { name, tags, favorite, cookTime, origins, price, img } = req.body;

const newFood = new FoodModel({
  name,
  tags,
  favorite,
  cookTime,
  origins,
  price,
  img,
});

try {
  const dbFood = await newFood.save();
  res.status(201).json(dbFood);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Kullanıcı kaydetme hatası:', err);
  res
    .status(500)
    .json({ message: 'Kullanıcı kaydedilirken bir hata oluştu' });
}
});
```

```
console.log(data)=undefined

console.log(file)=

fieldname: 'img',
  originalname: 'cv2.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: '../uploads/',
  filename: 'cv2.png',
  path: '..\\uploads\\cv2.png',
  size: 111862


console.log(this.formValue.value.img)=

lastModified: 
1687552608193
lastModifiedDate: 
Fri Jun 23 2023 23:36:48 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
name: 
"cv2.png"
size:
111862
type:
"image/png"
webkitRelativePath

console.log(response)=
img: 
contentType: 
"cv2.png"
data: 
undefined
```

Data still comes as undefined what is the source of the problem. Saving to file works, but I can't save data to db. Can I upload photos without using Buffer? Is it enough if I just save the name of the photo to the mongo db?